# A way of solving this PDE? (Other than method of characteristics)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I've been trying to work with this coupled PDE for some time. Here, $P = P(k,t)$

$$\frac{\partial{P}}{\partial t}-\frac{\sin(k)}{t}\frac{\partial{P}}{\partial k}=\left(\cos(k)-1\right){P}$$

To solve this PDE, I looked at the ODE

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=\left(\cos(k)-1\right)P$$

We know that

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} + \frac{dk}{dt}\frac{\partial P}{\partial k}$$

So we can see that whenever

$$\frac{dk}{dt}=\frac{-\sin(k)}{t}$$

the solution to the ODE gives us a solution to the PDE.

But is there another way to get a more general solution than this?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Is this still the method of characteristics?

Comment: @MatthewHunt Yes, it is.

Comment: Then why not just apply the method of characteristics straight off? Multiply through by $t$ and write $\dot{t}=t$, $\dot{k}=-\sin k$ and $\dot{p}=t(\cos k-1)$, this will set you up for the general solution.

Comment: @MatthewHunt Doesn't it give the solution only on the curves: $dk/dt = -(sin k)/t$ ?

Comment: Do you know how to use the method of characteristics to solve hyperbolic PDEs?

Comment: @MattewHunt Okay, I guess not. I'll learn it then. I got this PDE and thought of how solving the ODE on the curves $k(t)$ given by $dk/dt= -(sin k)/t$ will equal the solution to the PDE on those curves. A colleague told me that this was the method of characteristics.

Comment: I wrote some notes on the topic: http://hyperkahler.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/characteristics.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some notes on the solution of Poses by characteristics: http://hyperkahler.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/characteristics.pdf

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\partial{P}}{\partial t}-\frac{\sin(k)}{t}\frac{\partial{P}}{\partial k}=\left(\cos(k)-1\right){P}$$
$$\frac{dt}{1}=-t\frac{dk}{\sin(k)}=\frac{dP}{(\cos(k)-1)P}$$
From $\frac{dt}{1}=-t\frac{dk}{\sin(k)}$ :
$$t\tan(k/2)=c_1$$
From $-t\frac{dk}{\sin(k)}=\frac{dP}{(\cos(k)-1)P}=-\frac{c_1}{\tan(k/2)}\frac{dk}{\sin(k)}$

$\frac{dP}{P}=-c_1\frac{\cos(k)-1}{\tan(k/2)\sin(k)}dk=c_1dk$

$Pe^{-c_1k}=c_2$
$$Pe^{-t\tan(k/2)k}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE is :
$$P(k,t)=e^{t\tan(k/2)k}F\Big(t\tan(k/2)\Big)$$
where $F$ in an arbitrary function (to be determined if some sufficient boundary conditions are specified).

Comment: Say the boundary condition is $P(k,0) = 1$, can $F$ be determined then?

Comment: Also, $P(0,t)=1$.

Comment: @StatisticalMechanic: No, both initial conditions are stated on characteristic curves $c_1=0$, so that there may be solutions with $F(0)=1$, but they are not uniquely characterized, there is no initial condition for any other characteristic curve.

Comment: @StatisticalMechanic: The condition $P(k,0)=1$ is not sufficient to determine a unique solution. This means that with the condition $P(k,0)=1$ they are still an infinity of solutions. In the general solution given above, put any function $F$ such as $F(0)=1$ and you get a solution of the PDE which satisfies $P(k,0)=1$.